# How was $c = \bar{x}$ obtained from $\sum(x_i-c)^2$?

Tags: calculus, statistics

**Question from textbook:**

For what value of $c$ is the quantity $\sum(x_i-c)^2$ minimized?

Differentiating with respect to $c$, I obtained $-2 \sum (x - c)$. After finding the derivative I wasn't 100% sure how to solve for $c$ with the summation in there. When I checked my answer they did something completely different which I am very confused about.

**Textbook solution:**

$$(1.). -2 \sum (x - c) = 0$$

$$(2.)\sum x_i -nc = 0$$

$$(3.)n\bar{x} = nc$$

$$(4.)c = \bar{x}$$

**My Question:**

How did they get the n from step $2.$ and step $3.$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\bar x = \frac1n \sum x_i $
- so $n \bar x = \sum x_i$
- and thus  $\sum x_i -nc = 0\implies \sum x_i =nc \implies n \bar x =nc$

Comment: Ah ah ah! Thank you! That helps a lot!